# TextMate - use same icon as *.html.erb for *.html.haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, icons, haml, textmate

I use the Haml tempate system in my Rails apps and I imported into TextMate a plugin for coloring  Haml commands. That works me fine.

Now I have one more problem - all Haml files have the same icon, like the JS files (`*.html.haml` has the same icon, like `*.js` or `*.js.haml`).

Is there any option to have for `*.html.haml` the same icon as for `*.html.erb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a `Finder` issue. Select one of your `.haml` files in the Finder, and then **Get Info** (File > Get Info) on it.

(I'm on my iPhone now so can't remember *exactly* what it says in the Get Info dialog but…) You're looking for something like `Open with…` or `Open using`. Select that and choose **TextMate**. Then be sure to change the setting there to **open all `.haml` files with `TextMate`** (or something to that effect).

Should work? *May* need to relaunch TextMate?!?

**UPDATED:** looks like it's a bit more complicated - you need to update some resource data in the TextMate bundle itself. See top answer to this question: https://superuser.com/questions/178316/how-to-set-an-icon-for-a-file-type-on-mac

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately doesn't works me... yea, the file is opened in TextMate, but the icon of the file is still the same - unchanged.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that would do the trick. I updated answer with link to what would appear to be a way to accomplish this...short of waiting for **TextMate2**.